# Table centering with table-layout

Tags: css

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhEFk/) - here you got 2 exacly same styled tables. TD's width is auto adjusted by `table-layout.` It works ok, when there is only one line of text. But when there is more text and text is warped it seems like width is calculated by all the text (like it was in one line), not by  the longest warped part of text.

Question is how to center content of table nr 2 the same way as it is done in 1'st table? (atm it dont look like centered at all...)

[image] - this is how it should look (lower one) - dont needed yellow space should be cutted to allow table to be centered.

Comment: If you don't define table width or td width, You get this result. Because this is the what make sense.

Answer (score 2):

`td { text-align:center }`

The text in the first table isn't actually centered. It just appears that way because it has no breathing room on either side of the cell.

Making a global declaration like the above would allow additional tweaks to remaining cells.

`td.first { text-align:left; font-weight:700 }`, etc.

**EDIT**

You're not going to be able to achieve that effect without declaring a width. Tables don't act like `div`s by default, so I gave it `display:block, width:80%` and now the tables center, the `td` wasn't filling its parent correctly, so I gave it `width:100%`.

I think this is what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/hJXb9/

Comment: Its no matter that the first div is no centered, even with your style added, table is wider than is could be and becouse of that it is not centered as table.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UMFE4/1/ - thats how it should look like (but i've putted <br> knowing where it warps)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

```
    <table style="width:60%;margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="background:green;text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            TADA
        </td>
        <td style="background:yellow;text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;">
            Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet kjfldslggfh;l</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mack28/9NKqM/)

Hope, i will helps you. Thanks. !!

Comment: nope. I dont want green div to be left-aligned when it has free space. And it should stick to yellow one like here: http://jsfiddle.net/UMFE4/1/ (what i've done is <br> inserted in place where it warps - but I dont know when text will be warped in other case)

Comment: let me know if its helpful to you ?